# Коробочное кэширование в MySQL и Redis

Tags: mysql, кэширование, redis

Есть проект в котором используется БД MySQL. Я стараюсь по максимуму все данные в проекте кэшировать с помощью Redis. Но мы то знаем что в MySQL из коробки есть кэширование. Собственно стал вопрос, стоит ли отключить MySQL-кэширование? Я думаю от него нет пользы если все делается редисом, если отключить, будет ли лучше (я так понимаю - процесс кэширования средствами MySQL кушает определенные ресурсы) или я что-то могу потерять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL-кэширование - это не только кэширование результата, но и самого запроса, следовательно при включенном кэше, при подогреве записей в Redis-е, если искомый sql query уже есть в MySQL-кэше, то скорость получения данных будет значительно быстрее, нежели при отключенном MySQL-кэшировании. Исходя из описанного нужно понимать как часто происходит обращение к MySQL и как построена логика подогрева данных Redis-a.